# Android touch movement not responding

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have this code attached to a cube but it won't do a darn thing and I can't figure out why! The GUI Box triggers so I know the code works but the box just won't move. I've traced the touch count and phase and all is as it should be but my box won't budge an inch. Can anyone explain?

```
float speed;



bool touchDetect = false;



// Use this for initialization

void Start ()

{

    speed = 10.0f;

}



// Update is called once per frame

void Update()

{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)

    {

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)

        {



            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;);



            touchDetect = true;



        }

    }



    else

    {

        touchDetect = false;

    }

}



void OnGUI()

{

    if (touchDetect)

    {

        GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100), "Touch");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added a rigid body component to your cube??

Comment: I have indeed, I originally had the first person controller script on it but removed that and to add touch code. Thought these simple lines would work. There's no other code affecting position of the cube, just rotation. The rotation works fine and is based on the gyro.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a cube, no I'm not joking.
Your force is not enough to push a cube.
Try to set your speed = 1000; or using a sphere not cube, you will see what you want.